# How to implement parent child relation in doctrine with the same entity?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I try to create customElement contain another customElement with relation parent - child like three, one parent have many child but child have only one parent.

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\CustomElementRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=CustomElementRepository::class)
 */
class CustomElement
{

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=CustomElement::class, mappedBy="customElements")
     */
    private $customElements;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->customFields = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->customElements = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getCustomElement(): ?self
    {
        return $this->customElement;
    }

    public function setCustomElement(?self $customElement): self
    {
        $this->customElement = $customElement;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|self[]
     */
    public function getCustomElements(): Collection
    {
        return $this->customElements;
    }

    public function addCustomElement(self $customElement): self
    {
        if (!$this->customElements->contains($customElement)) {
            $this->customElements[] = $customElement;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeCustomElement(self $customElement): self
    {
        if ($this->customElements->contains($customElement))
            $this->customElements->removeElement($customElement);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

When i update database i have not column with id of parent.

[image: table schema]

How i can resolve this problem please? With doctrine is possible?

Thanks

Comment: I think you mixed up some stuff. It's doable, don't worry. `OneToMany` will create a table specific to this relation, it should be something like `custom_element_custom_elements` which will reference every mapping between entities. `ManyToOne` will create a field in your table which refer to the parent of object. By the way, your usage of `mappedBy` is wrong, it should be the property name on the "reverse" side. You should create a new property like `$parentCustomElement` if you really want to access their parent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

essentially, you *require only one* field to make a self-referencing relationship (many-to-one in your case).

However, you have the *partner* field defined (one-to-many), but not the owning field. Every relationship has an owning side, in this instance that's the one where you set the single parent element.

So, if you want both (and I want to say, it's perfectly reasonable and even useful!):

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(type="CustomElement", inversedBy="children")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", nullable=true)
 */
private $parent;
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(type="CustomElement", mappedBy="parent")
 */
private $children;
```

notes:

- pay attention on how the inversedBy and mappedBy attributes point to the respective other properties. it tells doctrine that those one-to-many/many-to-one belong to one another.
- the database column by default is named from the ManyToOne property name (`parent`) plus `_id` (so `parent_id`). you can override the naming with the `name` attribute in the `JoinColumn` annotation (as shown above). you can omit it, if the name in db already matches the generated one.
- the JoinColumn's `nullable=true` ensures, that you can add an Element without forcing it to have a parent, which AFAIK is necessary for a self-referencing many-to-one.
- the ManyToOne is the *owning* side. to set children for an entity, you have to set each of their `$parent` properties to that entity. (you can *additionally* add it/them to the `$children` property of the entity, if you want to work with it immediately. otherwise the children will be loaded the next time the entity is loaded from database)
- obviously before you can use this, you need to update the database structure/schema (via a migration, preferably)

for additional information, consult the doctrine docs about association mapping, as well as the annotation reference.